# How to get current url in angular?

Tags: angular, routes

i write below code in my `html` and at same time i use a method in my tag and navigate user to other `URL`:

```
<li class="">
        <p class="sideNavBarSubtitle-txt" style="cursor: pointer"
           (click)="clickSingle('content-production')"
           [ngClass]="{'current-txt' : linkActive == 'content-production'}"
           routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="./content/production">
          ایجاد محتوا</p></li>
```

here is my `clickSingle` method :

```
clickSingle(value) {
    if (!value) {
      this.linkActive = this.iconActive;
    } else {
      this.linkActive = value;
    }

    this.currentURL = this.router.url;
    console.log(this.currentURL);
  }
```

problem is here that i route user to `"./content/production"` but in my method at console i see `URL` of before page.

How can i fix this problem i need exactly current `URL`

Comment: It is because the click function is done in the previous page. You can fix the problem by getting the route after loading the new component.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `clickSingle` function is called inside the controller of the components that has the HTML portion you posted inside his view. What happens here is the following:

1. Click on the `<p>` item
2. `clickSingle()` method is called
3. `clicksingle()` method is executed and prints the current URL, which is not changed yet!
4. User is redirected to the new route: here the URL changes.

So, answering to your question, the method you use to get the current URL is correct. You simply do it in the wrong place.